# What's the usage of setBindingContext() and the difference from element binding?

Tags: sapui5

In the **1.5.2.3 Defining a Binding Path** section of OpenUI5 demokit:

> A context exists either for each entry of the aggregation in case of aggregation binding or can be set explicitly for a control by using the setBindingContext method.

In the **1.5.3.3 Element Binding** section of OpenUI5 demokit:

> Element binding allows to bind elements to a specific object in the model data, which will create a binding context and allow relative binding within the control and all of its children.

It seems to me that the two techniques actually do the same thing. They both create a binding context for a control so that bindings of the containing controls will resolve relatively to it. But what's the difference between them? In what scenario will either of them come into play?
The **setBindingContext** doesn't work in the following code:
https://jsbin.com/bigope/edit?html,output
However, if I change **oPanel.setBindingContext("/nameinfo");** to **oPanel.bindElement("/nameinfo");**, it works, why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`setBindingContext` requires you to pass a Context like this:

```
oPanel.setBindingContext(new sap.ui.model.Context(oModel, "/nameinfo"));
```

The difference between those two is conceptual. 
The Binding Context is used as a parent context for all bindings (for that model) in that Control or its children. It only holds a reference to the used model, (a part of) the path and optional another parent context. It is used when creating relative bindings.

The `bindElement` method on the other hand behaves like every other bind* method. 
It creates a binding (in this case, a `ContextBinding`) which allows change events, data binding, etc. 
Additionally the created `ContextBinding` also serves as a BindingContext for other bindings, just like a Context added with setBindingContext would do.

Not confusing at all, right ;)?

Reading the code for [ManagedObject](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/757b3ae391270984e400c9d1a518694666fb0fab/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/base/ManagedObject.js#L2695) might help you to understand the internals better. (bindObject = bindElement)